# JS / JSON / JQuery - How to insert Data into Json file lil css

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, json

Today i want to create a page that:
inserts things from a json file into divs but also allows you to add new infos to that json.
also i wanted to create a like button with increasing counter and sort function based on the likes.
I dont know anything about php or ajax. its maybe possible to solve without it ?
look here is my code. its not working yet obviously :)

But i hope you get the idea. I basically think iam heading the right direction but just missing some pieces :)

For designing i did put a div which containts 2 divs // 1 for img and 1 for text. i later want to style it with css so that each row there will be 2 filmbox divs and with css flexbox i want wrap it so when windows gets smaller only 1 box each row.

Like i make .filmbox{ width: 40%;} so theres space for only 2 each row and the other things gets wrapped down

[LAYOUT OF THE PAGE IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hikXm.png)

```
 // Copy Pastaed this ajax from internet to read json data from external file

    let readJSON = function (file) {
        let json = {}
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': file,
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    };

    let film = readJSON("film.json")
    console.table(film)


// Insert new Data to webpage

    for (let i in film){
            $(".content:eq("+i+")").append(`<div class="filmbox"><div class ="imgfield">
            <img src="${film[i].img}" ></div>"<div class="textfield"> <h1>" + film[i].name + "</h1>
            <br>" + film[i].description + "<br>" + 
            "<button type="button" id="button">LIKE</button>" + "<span id="likeCounter">
            </span></div></div>`); 

    }



    // Function to insert new Data into JSON from a from - Update website on Form click
    let film = []
    function getValues(){

    let filmName = $(#fname).value;
    let description = $(#fdescription).value;
    let img = $(#fimg).value;

    let filmData = [{
    "name" : ${filmname},
    "description" : ${description},
    "img" : $${img} 
    }]

    $(#formclick)on("click", ()=>{
    **// how to insert to json file ?**
    window.location.reload();

    })


    let counter = 0
    // Like Button Function
    $(#button).on("click", () =>{

    $(#likeCounter).text(counter++)

    )};

// SORT FUNCTION to first display films with the most likes
function orderDivs(){
counter.sort()
$(#button).find($counter) // Finds the value of likke button+
**Well and now sort all the Divs according to the like value the users did 
input (it dont need to save the like value  somewhere just when i like some films 
on the page by randomly clicking like it then should sort the divs according to that**

}

$(#sortbutton).on("click", ()=>{
orderDivs()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To save the data to a JSON file you'd typically post the data to a server that has file system access (e.g. PHP or Node.js).

If you want to do this client-side, you could look at the [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem), or persist the data in the browser with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Regarding the like button / count increment / sorting, it would be better to post this as a separate, more specific question.